# Delete dynamically created row : removechild

Tags: javascript, removechild

HTML :

```
<body style='background-color: white;'>

<div>
    <div id='dependent'>
        <input type="button" value="Add" id='abtn' onclick='addfunction()' />
        <input type="button" value="Delete" id='dbtn' onclick='deletefunction(this)' />
        <input type="button" value="Total No. of rows" id='Button2' onclick='total()'/>      <br />

    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" id='subid' onclick='smt()' /></div>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">




    function addfunction() {

        rcount++;
        t++;

        tr1 = document.createElement('tr');
        tr1.id = "t" + t;

        tx1 = document.createElement('p');
        text1 = document.createTextNode(t);
        tx1.appendChild(text1);

        td1 = document.createElement('td');
        td1.id = "da" + t;

        c1 = document.createElement('input');
        c1.type = "checkbox";
        c1.id = "a" + t;

        td2 = document.createElement('td');
        td2.id = "db" + t;
        c2 = document.createElement('input');
        c2.type = "checkbox";
        c2.id = "b" + t;

        td3 = document.createElement('td');
        td3.id = "dc" + t;
        c3 = document.createElement('input');
        c3.type = "checkbox";
        c3.id = "c" + t;


        dl1 = document.createElement('input');
        dl1.type = "button";
        dl1.id = "dl" + t;
        dl1.onclick = deletefunction; //Delete button for each row

        br1 = document.createElement('br');

        document.getElementById("dependent").appendChild(tr1);
        document.getElementById(tr1.id).appendChild(tx1);
        document.getElementById(tr1.id).appendChild(td1);
        document.getElementById(td1.id).appendChild(c1);
        document.getElementById(tr1.id).appendChild(td2);
        document.getElementById(td2.id).appendChild(c2);
        document.getElementById(tr1.id).appendChild(td3);
        document.getElementById(td3.id).appendChild(c3);
        document.getElementById(tr1.id).appendChild(dl1);
        document.getElementById(tr1.id).appendChild(br1);



//Delete Function
    function deletefunction() {
        alert('tr' + rcount);
        document.getElementById('tr' + rcount).removeNode(true);

    }




</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do i delete dynamically created row(or 'tr') using javascript?

I tried deleting it in two ways,

1. Separate delete button which will delete the last row.
2. Delete button on each row, to delete that particular row.

I tried various things but none works, i'm getting errors  as `" Unable to get value of the property 'removeNode': object is null or undefined".`

Comment: You'll get more help if you can find a way to simplify your code, bringing just the pertinent bits to the forefront.

Comment: Can u simulate the same on http://jsfiddle.net,will have a look at it

Comment: @levi Botelho - Thanks for your suggestion, i have edited my code, think its simpler to view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var row = document.getElementById('tr' + rcount);
row.parentElement.removeChild(row);
```

It also looks like you're not forming the `id` of the `tr` correctly. You have created it like this:

```
tr1.id = "t" + t;
```

then trying to read:

```
document.getElementById('tr' + rcount)
```

Also `rcount` seems not to be what you expect. It's a global variable, having the same value when `addfunction()` is last executed.

Comment: I got the following error, while trying your code :  " Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'parentElement': object is null or undefined"

Comment: @Vignesh When you alert the `id`, is `rcount`changing with different rows? Now it looks like it was a global variable, which will always has the last value assigned at the time the `deletefunction()` is executed.

Comment: no rcount is not changing, but even if the rcount doesn't change it should delete the last row which is added rite? i.e, the row id will be, for ex. 'tr' + rcount = tr4, so it will delete the last row(tr4).

Comment: Hmm... you didn't read my answer carefully, `"t4" !== "tr4"`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
var parNode=document.getElementById("dependent");
parNode.removeChild(parNode.childNodes[rowCount]);
```

Just provide the rowCount

Comment: Here the rowCount is deleting the elements inside the DIV, not the dynamically created rows.(For ex. it is deleting the delete button, spaces, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Little addition to @Teemu answer, for this case: Delete button on each row, to delete that particular row. -> single button. Since rcount doesn't return desired value... To delete multiple rows, maybe additional checkbox should be added...

So, this works only if you click on delete button in each row.

```
      function deletefunction() {


     id= $(this).attr('id');

    fin = id.replace(/\D+/, '');





    var row = document.getElementById('tr' + fin);
row.parentElement.removeChild(row);



    }
```

Also, script doesn't return right number of rows... it counts deleted rows too...